# ASP.NET MVC Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have just created a brand new ASP.NET MVC 4 project and when I run the project, I get the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Line 251:      <providers>
Line 252:        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
Line 253:        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
Line 254:      </providers>
Line 255:    </membership>
```

Any clue as to how I can fix this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: did you install mySQL Connector ?

Comment: @Sudhakar Should I have to? It's a brand spanking new project with 0 code amendments. I shouldn't have to install anything.

Comment: @Subby You're using a Microsoft product along with a none-Microsoft product, of course you have to install something.

Answer (score 0):

Using the MySql installer, mysql-installer-community-5.6.15.0.exe, I removed Connector/Net 6.7.4. That removed all MySql references from machine.config and fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you have to add the assambelies of other project to one of project that run

Comment: The reason someone voted you down is because you're practically saying this: He/she: My car won't run. You: Put fuel in it and you're done.